# Play (Scala) form validation error

Tags: validation, scala, playframework

I want to make a form validation in Play (Scala), I have done this several times but this time it shows error.. The error says:

> Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to
>   (play.api.data.Mapping[models.PIdetail])

Model:

```
package models

import java.util.Date
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current
import models._
case class Purchase_Invoice(supplier_id: String, paid_to_num: String, staff_id: String, paid_to_name: String, staff_name: String, paid_to_addr: String, PI_date: Date, PI_due_date: Date, payment: String, purchase_invoice_items: List[PIdetail], other: String, additional_note: String, terms_and_cond: String)
case class PIdetail(RI_id: Int, PO_id: String, product_id: String, description: String, qty: Int, total: String)
case class RIheader_PI(id_counter: Long, date_RI: Date, staff_id: String, status: Int)
```

Controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.format.Formats._
import play.api.mvc.Flash
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json._
import models._
object PurchaseInvoices extends Controller {
    val submitPIForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "supplier_id" -> text,
            "paid_to_num" -> text,
            "staff_id" -> text,
            "paid_to_name" -> text,
            "staff_name" -> text,
            "paid_to_addr" -> text,
            "PI_date" -> date,
            "PI_due_date" -> date,
            "payment" -> text,
            "purchase_invoice_items" -> list(
                mapping(
                    "RI_id" -> number,
                    "PO_id" -> text,
                    "product_id" -> text,
                    "description" -> text,
                    "qty" -> number,
                    "total" -> text
                )(PIdetail.apply)(PIdetail.unapply)
            ),
            "other" -> text,
            "additional_note" -> text,
            "terms_and_cond" -> text
        )(Purchase_Invoice.apply)(Purchase_Invoice.unapply)
    )
...................... Some codes
...................... Some codes
}
```

really need your help guys.. thanks before.. ^^

Comment: hmm cant see anything wrong with stuff posted here..

Comment: I agree, I copied your code into a test project in Eclipse and I get no compile errors. If you're using Eclipse, try cleaning the project. If you still have errors, post the whole code set to github or something. Typically you get an "apply" error if your apply or unapply arguments are malformed.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2.. I have cleared browser cache too, but still not working.. hmm.. Even when I put other form validation into this object PurchaseInvoices it shows the same error, but not in their own class.. Confused.. @.@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the error by myself.. ^^ 
It's because I have `def list = TODO` in my Controller.. 
So make sure you don't define a function/variable that has the same name with scala function..

Sorry to bother you guys... thx.. ^^